# inserting nothing in a .setText() method After loading textfile with FileReader

Tags: java, textfield, bufferedreader, filereader, illegalargumentexception

i'm finishing a java project for school but i'm stuck at a certain point.

The assignment is to make a task-planner which should be able t save tasks u add/edit or delete and save that information on a textfile in a directory on the computer.

This way everytime in the beginning when opening the app, the saved tasks-information gets loaded into the GUI..

the problem i'm facing is that i have to insert the information (when loading) in certain textfields in the GUI... however sometimes not all textfields should be completed - in other words it is not obligatory -

that's why sometimes a .setText() method will have an empty argument and the code won't work...

I tried solving the problem by inserting a " " (space) everytime it detects an empty argument - but i find this solution ugly since it applies that when clicking on a new GUI-window with a new empty TextField there will automatically be a space and the user should press backspace before writing something....

Is there a better solution for this ?

Here's the code that loads all the tasks...

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

 public class ReadTask extends Planner {

    public static void read(){

        String[] myArray = new String[8];
        String line = "";

        TaskWindowNew currentTask = null;

        try 
        {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("PlannerText.txt"));          

            while (( line = br.readLine()) !=null) 
            {
                myArray = line.split("\\|");

                for(int i=0;i<myArray.length;i++)
                {
                    if( myArray[i].isEmpty())
                    {
                        myArray[i] = "yoooo";
                    }
                }

                System.out.println(myArray.toString());

                try{
                    currentTask = new TaskWindowNew();
                    currentTask.popupFrame.setVisible(false);

                    // IMPORTANT = If one or more field(s) is left empty the .doClick function will not work
                    // we need to find a solution for this.
                    currentTask.titleField.setText(myArray[1]);
                    currentTask.minuteField.setText(myArray[2]);
                    currentTask.hourField.setText(myArray[3]);
                    currentTask.daysMonthField.setText(myArray[4]);
                    currentTask.MonthField.setText(myArray[5]);
                    currentTask.daysWeekField.setText(myArray[6]);
                    currentTask.specialSymbolField.setText(myArray[7]);

                    //this emulates the action of the OK-button in the new task window !
                    currentTask.buttonOk.doClick();

                 } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
                 {

                 }
            }

            br.close(); 

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        updateScrollPanel();


    }

}
```

Comment: never to create/set/modify the GUI or update GUI inside try - catch - finally

Comment: Imagine if the 2nd element is invalid. Then none of the code after it, including the the doClick method, will be executed. If its important, then you should add the doClick in the finally block of theory-catch

Comment: Where do you insert the `" "`? I can't seem to find it in your code. You could just do `a.setText("")`, so you wouldn't have the space.

Comment: It can be implemented on multiple ways. Personally I find these the easiest:
1 - do not store the strings in an array, but in a stringtokenizer, and set some unused character as delimiter. On this way it gives an empty string when you get back a part where two delimiters comes after each other. (or if it is empty, you can set null)
2 - create a serializable class with the data you want, it can be saved and loaded easily, and you can save null value easily also

Comment: @mKorbel:
I don't quite understand what u mean, why should i never do  this ?

Comment: @MadProgrammer:
ok i didn't know about this, seems a nice solution for the .doClick method ! thanx, however the space-problem still remains...

Comment: @Sam yes i'm sorry i didn't mention it by I also have an other class called SaveTask which puts a " " when the field is not filled in between the delimiters before saving the text-file. I tried not inserting a space but a "" instead, but then it comes down to the same problem and anyway I find this really ugly.

Comment: @skandigraun: I'm going to try to do it with a stringtokenizer seems nice ! tahnk u.

Comment: any GUI in all programing languages must be prepared before, variables from non safe Object (try - catch - finally) only returns value to concrete JComponent, on 1st exception your GUI never will be created, nor displayed

Comment: ok i understand thnx for the comment

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is closely coupled it with the file contents.Meaning at array index 1 there will be a title field or at index 3 an hours field.But if the user does not enter any value then the indexes change and you may get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in some cases.

So when the non-mandatory fields are not entered by the user, you cannot expect to display them on the UI the next time.

What you should do is rather to store key value pairs in the file.This will enable you to check what field is the value for rather than relying on the array index.

I mean something like this :

title:Mr

hours:four

specialSymbol:#

Then when you pre-populate it then you should get each line, split the key and value and if value is not empty then set it in the appropriate variable(which you will come to know from the key) of TaskWindowNew.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, yes that's a great idea ! i will try it out and say if it worked !

Answer (score 0):

Thnx everyone for the replies/comments

I solved the problem by erasing the myArray and directly assigning .split outcome to an array.
I'm not sure why it works like this...

For the ones interested in my SaveTask-class i save the data like this

```
outputStream.println(order + "|"+ title +"|"+ minutes +"|"+ hours +"|"+ daysPerMonth +"|"+ months +"|"+ daysPerWeek +"|"+ specialSymbol +"|"+"end");
order++;
```

but the following code wouldn't work without the "end"-flag at the end... otherwise it wouldnt make the array 8 slots long, it would just make it as long as the last TextField which was filled in.. (which gave me ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException-problems)

so that's how i fixed it.

I think @skandigraun is confused since a StringTokenizer actually does the opposite (i believe)

See here: http://www.coderanch.com/t/446893/java/java/Difference-split-StringTokenizer-nextToken

and the code that works:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

 public class ReadTask extends Planner {

    public static void read()
    {

        //try-catch for IOExceptions
        try 
        {
            //Make the inputStream
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("PlannerText.txt"));

            //The String containing each line
            String line = null;

            //For each line do the following
            while ( (line = br.readLine()) !=null) 
            {               
                //Make a new Task-window
                TaskWindowNew currentTask = new TaskWindowNew();

                //Set visibility to false
                currentTask.popupFrame.setVisible(false);

                //An array containing each string seperated by the delimiter
                String[] currTask = line.split("\\|");

                System.out.println(currTask.length);

                System.out.println(currTask[0]);

                //Fill each field with the corresponding String
                currentTask.titleField.setText(currTask[1]);
                currentTask.minuteField.setText(currTask[2]);
                currentTask.hourField.setText(currTask[3]);
                currentTask.daysMonthField.setText(currTask[4]);
                currentTask.MonthField.setText(currTask[5]);
                currentTask.daysWeekField.setText(currTask[6]);
                currentTask.specialSymbolField.setText(currTask[7]);

                //this emulates the action of the OK-button in the new task window !
                currentTask.buttonOk.doClick();
            }

            //Close the stream
            br.close(); 

        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        updateScrollPanel();            
    }
}
```